# Cannot update a table using a simple inner join

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, sql-update

I have 2 tables in access 2007.
See attached picture to see the structure of the tables and the expected result.

[image]

I am trying to update the quantity field (ITQTY) in TABLE_BLNC by summarizing all the quantity field (LOCQTY) from TABLE_DTL for same items (LOITNBR=ITNBR).
In TABLE_BLNC, the item is unique while in TABLE_DTL, the item can be in multiple records.

My query is:

```
UPDATE TABLE_BLNC INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT LOITNBR, Sum(LOCQTY) AS SumOfLOCQTY FROM TABLE_DTL GROUP BY LOITNBR) AS DTL 
ON TABLE_BLNC.ITNBR=DTL.LOITNBR SET TABLE_BLNC.ITQTY = DTL.SumOfLOCQTY;
```

I am getting the error:
Operation must use an updateable query.

Comment: So, in words (not SQL), what are you trying to do?

Comment: Syntax is wrong for an update using a join in T-SQL(Access, SQL server etc) - try looking at this answer and see if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql

Comment: I'd try `UPDATE TABLE_BLNC SET ITQTY = (select sum(.... WHERE ... TABLE_BLNC.ITNBR=DTL.LOITNBR...`

Comment: UPDATE TABLE_BLNC SET ITQTY=
(SELECT Sum(LOCQTY) AS SumOfLOCQTY
FROM TABLE_DTL 
GROUP BY TABLE_DTL.LOITNBR
WHERE TABLE_BLNC.ITNBR = TABLE_DTL.LOITNBR);
Is it what you meant? I am getting syntax error

Comment: Must `ITQTY` be a field which exists in the table?  Can you simply derive it when needed with a `SELECT` query like this? `SELECT TABLE_BLNC.ITNBR, Nz(sub.SumOfLOCQTY, 0) AS [ITQTY] FROM TABLE_BLNC LEFT JOIN (SELECT LOITNBR, Sum(LOCQTY) AS SumOfLOCQTY FROM TABLE_DTL GROUP BY LOITNBR) AS sub ON TABLE_BLNC.ITNBR=sub.LOITNBR;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Domain Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836861.aspx#Anchor_6) functions can be useful when Access complains that an `UPDATE` is not updateable.  In this case, use [DSum()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DSum-Function-08f8450e-3bf6-45e2-936f-386056e61a32?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) ...

```sql
UPDATE TABLE_BLNC
SET ITQTY = 
    DSum("LOCQTY", "TABLE_DTL", "LOITNBR='" & ITNBR & "'");
```

Index `TABLE_DTL.LOITNBR` for optimum performance.

Comment: This is the only workable suggestion so far, but I hesitate to endorse it because Domain Aggregate functions don't perform well for large data sets.

Comment: I think 'optimum' is overstating the benefit here. While indexing will likely improve performance with a Domain Aggregate function, it still is less efficient than a summary query. Maybe say 'better'?

Answer (score 1):

One of the great annoyances of Access SQL is its inability to update a table from an non-updatable source. Non-updatable sources include read-only links to ODBC tables, and GROUP BY (summary) queries.

What I always do is:

1. Copy the structure of `TABLE_BLNK` to a temp table: `TABLE_BLNK_temp`.
2. In your code, first delete the temp:

   ```
   DELETE * FROM TABLE_BLNK_temp;
   ```
3. Insert the result of your summary query into temp:

   ```
   INSERT INTO TABLE_BLNK_temp (ITNBR, ITQTY) 
   SELECT LOITNBR, Sum(LOCQTY) AS SumOfLOCQTY 
   FROM TABLE_DTL GROUP BY LOITNBR;
   ```
4. Update `TABLE_BLNK` from `TABLE_BLNK_temp`:

   ```
   UPDATE TABLE_BLNC INNER JOIN TABLE_BLNK_temp AS t 
       ON TABLE_BLNC.ITNBR = t.ITNBR
   SET TABLE_BLNC.ITQTY = t.ITQTY;
   ```

While it is an extra step or two, this approach:

- Always works
- Is more performant than Domain Aggregate functions for larger datasets